Injecting a bean dependency inside Condition or ConfigrationCondition
I have a class named as My condition which implements Spring Condition interface. I need to inject another Spring bean into MyCondition as this dependency is going to make call to database and check if this configuration should be enabled or not.
    @Conditional(MyCondition.class)
@Configuration
//Few annotations like //EnableCaching etc
public class MyConfig {} 

@Component
public class MyCondition implements Condition{
   @Autowired
   private MyBean myBean;
public boolean matches(....) {
  return `myBean.getFlag().equals("Y")`;
}
}

But this doesn't work as myBean is not initialised by the time this condition is evaluated. I have also tried ConfigurationCondition but still the same issue.
Using env.getContext.getBeanFactory to get the bean inside matches also doesn't work.
Please tell me if there is any way to use another bean inside class which implements Condition or ConfigurationCondition.
Alternatively, please feel free to answer if there is another way to include or exclude a Configuration class.
Thanks.

Conditions are processed very early in the startup process without all the beans having been configured as that is used to determine if a bean needs to be configured or not. Hence injection will not work here, if you are lucky you might be able to obtain the datasource (but I doubt it), so your only option would be to create a datasource locally based on the configuration and query yourself.

You are right that I can't even get the data source which is present in a common library project. It's not able to resolve the properties used while creating data source.

You cannot directly inject a bean dependency into a class that implements the Condition or ConfigurationCondition interface. These conditions must follow the same restrictions as BeanFactoryPostProcessor and should not interact with bean instances.

So this means that the usage of these Conditions is very limited. Is it only good enough if we are using application properties?
